# How to Return an Class with an Array in Java webservices Consumed by C#

Tags: java, c#, eclipse, web-services, wsdl

I am having trouble creating a java webservice that returns an Array inside a class. I created a java websrevice with a class and inside the class I created a new Array that will return another Class. But when Importing the WSDL in a C# project I cant access the Array inside the class.

My java web service example :

My industry class :

```
public class Industry {

        public int industryID;
        public String industryName;
        public Product[ ] products;


}
```

The Idea is to return the industry with all the products of the industry.

The Product Class :

```
public class Product {

    public int productID;
    public String productName;



}
```

My webservice that populates the industry and the  Products for the Industry. Please nte I know I am suposed to create get and set methods to set the values.. I only created a small examle of my problem.

My Webservice class :

```
public class IndustryService {
    /**
     * @param industryID
     * @return industry object
     */
    public Industry getIndustryData(int industryID){

        Product product1 = new Product();
        product1.productID = 712;
        product1.productName = "Sensor Light";

        Product product2 = new Product();
        product2.productID = 1774;
        product2.productName = "Light Beamer";

        Product [] products = new Product[] { product1, product2 };

        Industry industry = new Industry();
        industry.industryID = 2311;
        industry.industryName = "Test";
        industry.products = products;

        return industry;
    }
}
```

Here's the WSDL that gets generated in java :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://server.com" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://server.com" xmlns:intf="http://server.com" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)-->
 <wsdl:types>
  <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://server.com" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <element name="getIndustryData">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="industryID" type="xsd:int"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
   <element name="getIndustryDataResponse">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="getIndustryDataReturn" type="impl:Industry"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
   <complexType name="Product">
    <sequence>
     <element name="productID" type="xsd:int"/>
     <element name="productName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="ArrayOfProduct">
    <sequence>
     <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" type="impl:Product"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="Industry">
    <sequence>
     <element name="industryID" type="xsd:int"/>
     <element name="industryName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="products" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOfProduct"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
  </schema>
 </wsdl:types>

   <wsdl:message name="getIndustryDataResponse">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:getIndustryDataResponse" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="getIndustryDataRequest">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:getIndustryData" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:portType name="IndustryService">

      <wsdl:operation name="getIndustryData">

         <wsdl:input message="impl:getIndustryDataRequest" name="getIndustryDataRequest">

       </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output message="impl:getIndustryDataResponse" name="getIndustryDataResponse">

       </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:portType>

   <wsdl:binding name="IndustryServiceSoapBinding" type="impl:IndustryService">

      <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

      <wsdl:operation name="getIndustryData">

         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

         <wsdl:input name="getIndustryDataRequest">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output name="getIndustryDataResponse">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:binding>

   <wsdl:service name="IndustryServiceService">

      <wsdl:port binding="impl:IndustryServiceSoapBinding" name="IndustryService">

         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080//IIIII/services/IndustryService"/>

      </wsdl:port>

   </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Now when consuming it using  c# I expect to get a Industry Containing 2 products but C# shows that theres 0 inside of product array...

C# example created a normal form and imported the java WSDL as service reference:

[image]

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceReference1.IndustryServiceClient client = new WindowsFormsApplication4.ServiceReference1.IndustryServiceClient();

            ServiceReference1.Industry m = client.getIndustryData(2);

            string a = "test";

        }
```

When I debug windows form I get the following :

[image]

Notice the Product Array count is 0?

Why is this zero and What am I doing wrong?

Is the problem in the java side or c# side?

I am using eclipse to create the java webservice and Visual studio to import wsdl.

In soap UI I also imported the WSDL just to test the webservice to see the request and response and It looks correct :

Request :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://server.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:getIndustryData>
         <ser:industryID>2</ser:industryID>
      </ser:getIndustryData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <getIndustryDataResponse xmlns="http://server.com">
         <getIndustryDataReturn>
            <industryID>2311</industryID>
            <industryName>Test</industryName>
            <products>
               <productID>712</productID>
               <productName>Sensor Light</productName>
            </products>
            <products>
               <productID>1774</productID>
               <productName>Light Beamer</productName>
            </products>
         </getIndustryDataReturn>
      </getIndustryDataResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Code in the reference.cs file I edited :

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute(Name="products", Namespace="http://server.com", ItemName="item")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class ArrayOfProduct : System.Collections.Generic.List<WindowsFormsApplication4.ServiceReference1.Product> {
}
```

In the Reference.cs file I changed the Name and ItemName tag to Products and now it is working.

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute(Name = "products", Namespace = "http://server.com", ItemName = "products")]
```

Comment: Look at the message itself to figure out problem. I.e. use Fiddler HTTP debugger to capture requests and look at them.

Comment: What is the value of "productse" in the response? Your Industry class does not have a field with this name and it seems like Elipse is adding it to the WSDL

Comment: @OguzOzgul Sorry about that I updated to the WSDL to the corect one.. productse was when I tetsed the code with a Get function. Please check the WSDL again.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks I Added the request and response to my question, It looks correct to me.

Comment: Ok the problem is, Visual Studio creates the stub and expects the elements of products with the tag name "ArrayOfProduct" but the server sends them with the tag <products>. See the reference.cs file under the service reference (you need to check the Show All Files for the project). It is not a good practice, but to resolve the issue, you can manipulate the reference.cs file manually to change the CollectionDataContractAttribute to "products" on top of the definition of public class ArrayOfProduct

Comment: Or if you can, specify on the Java side to use the tag name <ArrayOfProducts> for the products array

Comment: Dear @Renier, can you please upvote if this was helpful? Or at least let us know about whether your problem has been solved or not.

Comment: @OguzOzgul Thanks for you response,  I will when I tested this currently just busy with production problem.

Comment: Sure. Sorry for the production issue by the way.. Wish you good luck with it.

Comment: @OguzOzgul I changed the "ArrayOfProducts" to "products" in the Reference.cs But when I tested it again in c# the Count of products still 0.. Please see above code that I changed.

Comment: @OguzOzgul Will it work if I modify the WSDL? And waht should I modify?

Comment: @OguzOzgul I got it working as you said by changing the ArrayOfProducts to Products but I had to also change the ItemName to Products before it worked. Please see edited Post.

Comment: How will I be able to change it in the java side so that it gets imported correctly in c#?

Comment: I think you should configure the web service to generate the xml as expected by the client, as such, the products array should be serialized as <products><Product>..</Product></products> instead of the current list. I don't know how to do that. Sorry

Comment: I might suggest a solution however; a workaround which sometimes we have to apply to our .net classes to achieve expected xml output when they are serialized. You can try to wrap the Product[ ] products field of the Industry class on server side in another class like ProductCollection, and can add a dummy public variable (we mostly use int dummy). I think in that case, the java web service and .net client (when service reference is updated) will be able communicate without client stub modifications. Worth trying I guess..

Comment: Looking at the complexType definition of ArrayOfProducts again, the java web service breaks the wsdl contract it generated by returning an nonconformant xml. According to the wsdl, it should return the ArrayOfProducts like the following <products><item>..</item><item>..</item></products> but it does not. Does this point to a much more general issue with Eclipse or Java Web Services then?

Comment: @OguzOzgul IF you answer the question with the rename of ArrayOfProducts to "Products" like in your comment,  I will accept it as the answer. I am going to use it for now as a work around. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I am happy that your problem is resolved. .Net and Java still seem to have compatibility issues even with very well defined standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio creates the stub and expects the elements of products with the tag name "ArrayOfProduct" but the server sends them with the following tag

```
<products>
```

See the reference.cs file under the service reference (you need to check the Show All Files for the project).

It is not a good practice, but to resolve the issue, you can manipulate the reference.cs file manually to change the CollectionDataContractAttribute to "products" on top of the definition of public class ArrayOfProduct